# Dynamic change ResultsPerPage in CoreResultWebPart (Search)

Tags: search, search-results

I would like to ask if some do not face this requirement:

Client wants to have search fully configurable by taking properties from SPFarm bag. This means that he wants to set up number of results per page in search result form for example.

I overridden `ConfigureDataSourceProperties` method and in this method I am assigning value to `ResultsPerPage` property. However this is probably late because it take value that is set in the text box of web part settings. So my question is where I should set the ResultsPerPage property? I would like to ignore text in OOB Results per page text box. I also don't want to use the approach with checking-out the page, taking the web part manager etc .. Is there an option?

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

well after closer look i found the solution.

```
var dataSource = DataSource as CoreResultsDatasource;
dataSource.ResultsPerPage = desiredResultsPerPage
```

I also set

```
this.ResultsPerPage = desiredResultsPerPage
```

however I dont know if this step is needed :)